# Handle Discord Py timeouterror with one method?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was just wondering if there was an efficient way to handle all the timeout errors in a single class with one method. I currently have several methods that have a timeout of varying seconds and since they all just have the same generic message prompts of letting the user know that the waiting period is over, perhaps there can be a single method that is called when the timeout is triggered? maybe something similar to an @methodname.error but for the entire class, not just one method or under a try catch for each command

Comment: There isn't. Make one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a bot from `discord.ext.commands.Bot`, you can use the `on_command_error` event to handle generic command errors:

```py
from asyncio import TimeoutError


@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, TimeoutError):
        await ctx.reply(f"Response timeout reached.")
    elif isinstance(error, AnotherException):
        ...
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume this will work for all cogs if I put this inside my main.py?

Comment: Yes. This is a global error handler